# how to make websocket secure connection in php socket

Tags: php, ssl, websocket

I am making a chatroom using WebSockets, which is working fine when I use an unencrypted connection, but after I use a certificate it doesn't work anymore.

In JavaScript I was opening the connection to the WebSocket server at `serverr.php` like this:

```js
var wsUri = "ws://mydomain.com:9002/chat/serverr.php"; 
websocket1 = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

Now I know that I must use `wss://` instead of `ws://` so now I am using:

```js
var wsUri = "wss://mydomain.com:9002/chat/serverr.php";
websocket1 = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

But I get the following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com:9002/chat/serverr.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

But I don't know how to make a `wss://` connection. I tried to modify my code with the following part:

```php
set_time_limit(0);

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../../../home/username/public_html/config/config.php");


$host = 'ssl://0.0.0.0'; //host
$port = '9002'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

// Generate certificate
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
$cert    = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);
$cert    = openssl_csr_sign($cert, null, $privkey, 365);

// Generate PEM file
# Optionally change the passphrase from 'comet' to whatever you want, or leave it empty for no passphrase
$pem_passphrase = 'comet';
$pem = array();
openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem[0]);
openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $pem[1], $pem_passphrase);
$pem = implode($pem);

// Save PEM file
$pemfile = 'server.pem';
file_put_contents($pemfile, $pem);


//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pemfile);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pem_passphrase);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
//the rest of code is still unmodified is like in the page serverr.php
```

Code in `serverr.php`

```php
set_time_limit(0);

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../../../home/username/public_html/config/config.php");


$host = 'localhost'; //host
$port = '9002'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);
perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port);
//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        //luam ultimele 15 mesaje start     
        $cerereinitialachat=mysqli_query($conexiune,"SELECT * FROM `chat_messages` ORDER BY `datesend` DESC LIMIT 17");
        $obiectinitialchat=null;
        $obiectobjectcount=0;
        while ($rezultat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cerereinitialachat)) {
            $row=$rezultat;

            $id;
            $sender_steamid;
            $avatar;
            $sender_name;
            $message;
            $datesend;
            $steamprofile;
            $color;

            foreach($row as $key=>$value){
                if($key=="id"){
                    $id=$value;
                }
                if($key=="sender_steamid"){
                    $sender_steamid=$value;
                }
                if($key=="avatar"){
                    $avatar=$value;
                }
                if($key=="sender_name"){
                    $sender_name=$value;
                }
                if($key=="message"){
                    $message=$value;
                }
                if($key=="datesend"){
                    $datesend=$value;
                }
                if($key=="steamprofile"){
                    $steamprofile=$value;
                }
                if($key=="color"){
                    $color=$value;
                }           
            }

            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]=new stdClass;

            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]->avatar=$avatar;
            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]->name=$sender_name;
            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]->message=$message;
            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]->datesend=$datesend;
            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]->steamprofile=$steamprofile;
            $obiectinitialchat[$obiectobjectcount]->color=$color;
            $obiectobjectcount=$obiectobjectcount+1;        
        }
        //luam ultimele 15 mesaje stop

        $cererenumaruonline=mysqli_query($conexiune,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `online`!='0'");   
        $numaruonline=mysqli_num_rows($cererenumaruonline);

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected', 'uonline'=>$numaruonline, 'lastmessages'=>$obiectinitialchat))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1){

            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_steamid  = esc($conexiune,$tst_msg->steamid); //sender steamid
            $user_avatar = esc($conexiune,$tst_msg->avatar); //avatar
            $user_name  = esc($conexiune,$tst_msg->name); //sender name
            $user_message = esc($conexiune,$tst_msg->message); //message text
            $user_steamprofile = esc($conexiune,$tst_msg->steamprofile); //steamprofile
            $user_message_date = time(); //message text date

            $user_message=preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $user_message);//scoate enterurile
            if (ctype_space($user_message)) {
                //daca e numai spatiii libere(albe)
                $user_message=preg_replace('/\s+/', "", $user_message);//scoate spatiile albe
            }

            $admin;   
            $color="normal";                
            $raspuns=mysqli_query($conexiune,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid`='".$user_steamid."'");
            while($rezultat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($raspuns)){
                $row=$rezultat;
                foreach($row as $key=>$value){            
                    if($key=="dirijor"){
                        $admin=$value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($admin=="Yes" || $user_steamid=="76561197997524415"){
                $color="red";
            }

            if($user_steamid!="" && $user_steamid!=null && $user_message!="" && $user_message!=null){
                mysqli_query($conexiune,"INSERT INTO `chat_messages` (`sender_steamid`,`avatar`,`sender_name`,`message`,`datesend`,`steamprofile`,`color`) VALUES ('".$user_steamid."','".$user_avatar."','".$user_name."','".$user_message."','".$user_message_date."','".$user_steamprofile."','".$color."')");

                //prepare data to be sent to client
                $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'avatar'=>$user_avatar, 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'datesend'=>$user_message_date, 'steamprofile'=>$user_steamprofile, 'color'=>$color)));
                send_message($response_text); //send data
            }           
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            $cererenumaruonline2=mysqli_query($conexiune,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `online`!='0'");  
            $numaruonline2=mysqli_num_rows($cererenumaruonline);
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'upadateusersonline','uonline'=>$numaruonline)));
            send_message($response);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            //$response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            //send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Comment: Most likely the browser rejects the self signed certificate. Have you tried using a certificate from StartSSL (Class 1 SSL Certificates are free) or any other trusted CA?

Comment: have one but i don't know how to use it in the php

Comment: Pass the path to it to your `socket_set_option` which sets the local certificate.

Comment: but this is correct socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pemfile); ? with that 'ssl' ?

Comment: getting same issue what describes,I have the .key and .cert files on server but how to use on php file to check handshaking?

Comment: `socket_set_option` only accepts 4 parameters. Where were you told to send in 5?